# Shirk in my head while praying

Tags: salat, shirk, forgiveness

I was praying and I thinking about how I always doubt my prayers and in my head I said “I know I prayed the right amount of rakahs, I swear on my life.” As soon I realized what I said in my head my heart dropped and I asked Allah for forgiveness repeatedly. Did I commit shirk?

Answer (score 0):

Learning is a progression. The more you learn, the more knowledgeable you become, the more you tend to be aware of your mistakes and aberrations, and most importantly, the more you are likely to ward off such mistakes.